# How do you add slice spacing to just the selected item of a pie chart with iOS Charts in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am using the [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library by Daniel Gindi.
I am able to set my delegate and have a function run whenever a slice is selected, but the line pieChartDataSet.sliceSpace sets the spacing for the entire chart instead of just one slice.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you please explain how you put text in every slice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168148/how-to-alligned-text-on-piechart-or-piechart-slice-center

Answer (score 1):

chartView.highlightValue(x: 0, dataSetIndex: 0)

Answer (score 0):

This `pieChartDataSet.sliceSpace` is for highlight feature, and you just have to write code to highlight the slice you want.

Take a look at `drawHighlighted()` in pie chart renderer.